# MySQL - Updating a table from another table

Tags: c#, mysql

I am writing a small app (c#/WPF/MySQL).  One of things that I want to do is to update some product descriptions within a table.

Here is a slightly altered version of the query that I thought could be the starting point:

```
SELECT
    `egx_machine`.`contact_id` AS `contact_id`,
    `egx_machine`.`gtr2_product_family` AS `gtr2_product_family`,
    `egx_machine`.`gtr2_product_family_factory` AS `gtr2_product_family_factory`,
    `egx_machine`.`gtr2_product_family_model` AS `gtr2_product_family_model`,
    `egx_machine`.`gtr2_product_family_size` AS `gtr2_product_family_size`,
    `egx_machine_extra`.`contact_name` AS `contact_name`,
    `gtxuk_r2_machine`.`machine_desc` AS `machine_desc`,
    `gtxuk_r2_machine`.`product_family` AS `product_family`,
    `gtxuk_r2_machine`.`factory` AS `factory`,
    `gtxuk_r2_machine`.`model` AS `model`,
    `gtxuk_r2_machine`.`size` AS `size`
FROM (((`egx_machine`
    JOIN `egx_machine_extra`
        ON ((`egx_machine`.`contact_id` = `egx_machine_extra`.`contact_id`)))
    JOIN `gtxuk_machine`
        ON ((`egx_machine_extra`.`contact_value` = `gtxuk_machine`.`machine_id`)))
    JOIN `gtxuk_r2_machine`
        ON ((CONVERT(`gtxuk_machine`.`machine_desc` USING utf8) = `gtxuk_r2_machine`.`machine_desc`)))
WHERE (`egx_machine_extra`.`contact_name` = 'mac_type')
```

But somehow, I need to turn this into an update query where:

```
`egx_machine`.`gtr2_product_family` = `gtxuk_r2_machine`.`product_family`
and
`egx_machine`.`gtr2_product_family_factory = `gtxuk_r2_machine`.`factory`
```

I know it's a bit long winded - but I started off with a full head of hair and now look like kojak.

Comment: update on which table ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the values in the product table you can do as

```
update 
products p
join products_new_data pn on pn.product_name = p.product_name
set 
p.product_name_new = pn.product_name_new ,
p.product_source = pn.product_source ;
```

For doing it reverse you can do as

```
update 
products_new_data pn
join products p on p.product_name = pn.product_name
set 
pn.product_name_new  = p.product_name_new,
pn.product_source = p.product_source ;
```

**UPDATE**

From the comments I guess this is what you are looking at, however its really hard to write a query without the schema and some data, but I think this should be pretty close what you are looking at if I am not misunderstood your question

```
update egx_machine em
JOIN egx_machine_extra emx on emx.contact_id = em.contact_id
JOIN gtxuk_machine gm on emx.contact_value = gm.machine_id
JOIN gtxuk_r2_machine g2m on CONVERT(gm.machine_desc USING utf8) = g2m.machine_desc
set 
em.gtr2_product_family = g2m.product_family ,
em.gtr2_product_family_factory = g2m.factory
```

Comment: That's great - thank you (again).  However, I've just spotted that I need to use a third (related) table.  Can an update query handle this?

Comment: Post the tables in the question and what exactly you are looking at.

Comment: I wish I could - but I'm not allowed too (even queries).  I'll have a quick look at your original example, and if I need to I'll post something that at least gives you an idea.  Thanks again though - I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: looked at the query and joining is done between 4 tables. So thats straight forward but which table should be updated with data from which table ? Thats pretty unclear. You mentioned about the where clause which must be fulfilled that fine, but for update you need to know which fields you are updating and from which table they should be retrieved.

Comment: Hi - `egx_machine` is the table that needs to be updated, the fields within this table are called `gtr2_product_family_factory` and `gtr2_product_family`.  These fields need to be updated from a table called `gtxuk_r2_machine` and the fields of `product_family` and `family` respectively.

Comment: I thought that saving this as a SELECT query called TEST and then updating the values of TEST might be the way to go, but I don't think that's it.

Comment: It's still not quite there, but I have a feeling it's my end.  I'm going to try a slightly different approach, through a new question (and then come back to this afterwards).  Sorry to drag it out - but thanks again.